# What is the easiest way to use the HEAD command of HTTP in PHP?

Tags: php, http, protocols, head

I would like to send the HEAD command of the Hypertext Transfer Protocol to a server in PHP to retrieve the header, but not the content or a URL. How do I do this in an efficient way?

The probably most common use-case is to check for dead web links. For this I only need the reply code of the HTTP request and not the page content.
Getting web pages in PHP can be done easily using `file_get_contents("http://...")`, but for the purpose of checking links, this is really inefficient as it downloads the whole page content / image / whatever.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As an alternative to curl you can use the http context options to set the request method to `HEAD`. Then open a (http wrapper) stream with these options and fetch the meta data.

```
$context  = stream_context_create(array('http' =>array('method'=>'HEAD')));
$fd = fopen('http://php.net', 'rb', false, $context);
var_dump(stream_get_meta_data($fd));
fclose($fd);
```

see also:
 http://docs.php.net/stream_get_meta_data
 http://docs.php.net/context.http

Comment: I prefer this solution over the ones using curl, because I like using built-in functions. Maybe somebody else can comment on the performance of each possibility?

Comment: Note that this will throw an error for `401` response codes, while curl provides you with the actual response.

Comment: `stream_context_create()` can be used also with `file_get_contents()`. Maybe `get_headers()` is much better combined with `stream_context_set_default()` to the method of the request to <code>HEAD</code>. See http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-headers.php

Answer (score 29):

You can do this neatly with [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource with the url
$ch = curl_init( "http://www.example.com/" );     

// This changes the request method to HEAD
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

// Execute curl with the configured options
curl_exec($ch);

// Edit: Fetch the HTTP-code (cred: @GZipp)
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 

// To print the response code:
print( $code);

// To check the size/length:
$length = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD); 

// To print the content_length:
print( "<br>\n $length bytes");


// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 5):

Even easier than curl - just use the PHP`get_headers()`function which returns an array of all header info for any URL you specify.  And another real easy way to check for remote file existence is to use`fopen()`and try to open the URL in read mode (you'll need to enable allow_url_fopen for this).

Just check out the PHP manual for these functions, it's all in there.

Comment: `get_headers()` will actually send a 'GET' request unless you do this first: `stream_context_set_default(array('http'=>array('method'=>'HEAD')));`

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using [Guzzle Client](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle), it's based on the CURL library but more **simple** and **optimized**.

installation:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

example in your case:

```
// create guzzle object
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

// send request
$response = $client->head("https://example.com");

// extract headers from response
$headers = $response->getHeaders();
```

Fast and easy.

[Read more here](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like pear has it:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http.head.php

Answer (score 0):

Just as a complement to PHP, maybe someone came here looking for ways to **see** HEAD verb working in the browser, and Ajax also allows you to use it in the same way as GET and POST.

The best part of this info is that Ajax allows us to see in the browser inspector (Network tab) the actual method HEAD being executed. PHP Curl runs on the server side, so, browser inspector will show only the GET for the php file, but not the curl HEAD operation. This is for Ajax:

```
xmlhttp.open("HEAD", url);
xmlhttp.send();
```

In the same way when "readystatechanges" you get

```
xmlhttp.status // (200 meaning 'OK, success', 404 'not found', etc)
```

To retrieve header props like "Content-Length", after getting the status 200, in the same block of code, you can retrieve these props using:

```
 xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
 // and for all:
 xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders();
```