# check if a site exists with PHP

Tags: php

is there a script in php to check if a site exists in the world wide web?

1. submit a url
2. script check if site is existing
3. return true if it does

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545432/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-use-the-head-command-of-http-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation using CURL:

> [Check website status using php and CURL library](http://php.assistprogramming.com/check-website-status-using-php-and-curl-library.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can just try to issue an HTTP request and see if something comes back.

Comment: uh...sorry for the noob question but what headers do I have to check to see if something comes back?

Comment: Well, a response code of 200 would be a good start. And if no site exists then you'll probably not get anything but an error or a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst firing off an HTTP request will tell you if a site exists, it doesn't tell you whether the domain has been registered but is not currently in use. If this is something that you'd need to be able to do, you need to use a [WHOIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) service to check whether the domain is registered or not.