# PHP cheapest way how to check if remote image exist

Tags: php

I want to check if a remote image exist.
Currently using CURL and based on its response to i can determine if the file exist. 
However, this takes a fare bit amount of time depending on the image file size also.

Is there a safest and cheapest way of doing a check without doing it offline or using cache?

```
$ch = curl_init();
        // set URL and other appropriate options
        /*--Note: if in sabre proxy, please activate the last 4 lines--*/
        $options = array(   CURLOPT_URL => $img,
                            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,  // get the header
                            CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,  // body not required
                            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => false,  // get response as a string from curl_exec, not echo it
                            CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => false,  // don't use a cached version of the url
                            CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true,
                            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5
                        );


        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

        if(!curl_exec($ch)) { return FALSE; } 

        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close($ch);

        return ($httpcode<400);
```

Comment: You can send HEADER instead of GET to only know what would the response be without downloading the file, but how to do it in curl I don't know.

Comment: @Dani: it's `HEAD`, not `HEADER`.

Answer (score 5):

[Perform a HEAD request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545432/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-use-the-head-command-of-http-in-php) and check the response code.

Comment: Then there's nothing you can do. The server is just slow.

Comment: @flyclassic: using `CURLOPT_NOBODY` issues a `HEAD` request, that's why they're the same.