# How can I proxy a request using PHP/cURL and proxy the response headers too?

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I have a browser client that's fetching partial content from my web service, e.g. using `Range: bytes=100000-200000`.  The request comes into a PHP page, fetch.php.  In that PHP page, I grab the requested Range using `$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']` then set it into the curl request using `curl_setopt` - `CURLOPT_RANGE`.  The problem I have is, the remote server is responding with a `206 Partial Content` status and `Content-Range` header, but my PHP page just responds with a `200 OK` and no `Content-Range` so the result is a partial file that the client thinks is complete.  The question is, how do I set in PHP the resulting `Content-Range` to the original request?

If I knew the range up front, which I don't, I could just use the `header` command and be done with it, but the Range is returned in the response.  I could set in curl to receive the all headers with the content then parse out the header, set it using `header` and set the response to 206 then echo out all the data... but the data is binary, not to mention very large, so this seems sub-optimal, at best.

I was wondering if I could somehow set an option in PHP to not send ANY headers of it's own, and basically just echo the entire response back to the requester.  Without fully thinking this through, it could be problematic with other headers though, caching, connection, proxies, etc.

Perhaps there's a way I could receive just the headers from curl (some kind of partial_execute?), get what I need, set the header and response code, then basically complete the exec and the actual response get's output directly?  I can't see from curl how to make that happen.

Setting up an actual reverse-proxy isn't really an option either, since the PHP script actually determines the target server for the resource (it's not static).

I suppose I could just skip using curl and do a TCP/TLS connection directly and manage the HTTP request/response.

Any additional ideas or possibilities?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It may or may not be the best solution, but it works in the scenario I needed.  Basically just do my own HTTP(S) fetch using `stream_socket_client` making sure to pass along the necessary response code and headers, like:

```
while ( true ) {
    $h = stream_get_line( $fp, 2048, "\r\n");
    if ( !$h ) {
        break;
    }
    if ( 0==strncasecmp( $h, 'Content-', 8 ) ) {
        header( $h );
    }
    else if ( 0==strncasecmp( $h, 'HTTP/1.', 7 ) ) {
        header( $h );
    }
}

fpassthru( $fp );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps there's a way I could receive just the headers from curl

This is part of the HTTP protocol, see: [What is the easiest way to use the HEAD command of HTTP in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545432/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-use-the-head-command-of-http-in-php)

I don't understand what the problem is otherwise.

If you are getting partial responses it could be due to connection timeout. This can be changed using:

CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT

Comment: I've got a client and 2 servers, proxy and actual server: C->P->S.  The client is requesting partial content via the Range header.  The proxy passes the request to the server using curl.  The server correctly responds with the 206 partial content.  However, the PHP proxy response goes back as a 200 OK so it looks to the client like the proxy ignored the partial part of the request and just did a full response when in fact it is partial.  Somehow I need curl and PHP to return that it has satisfied the response as correctly partial.

Comment: Still not 100% sure on this, but it seems to me, you are requesting a 206 header by one server and then sending it on from another. Wouldn't you need to do something like start that page with: <?php
header("HTTP/1.0 206 Partial Content");
?>

Comment: You are correct, I could force the response code like you said, but as far as I know I cannot get the Content-Range from the main server's response to put that header.  I can get curl to return the headers, but it returns all the content as well (which I'd rather not have in one big massive string)... I don't see a way of getting the headers without getting the content.  In the end, I ended up successfully using a stream_socket_client and not curl; I'll post that as an answer in this question just in case someone else stumbles upon this.